# MySQL: condition on result of GROUP_CONCAT?

Tags: mysql, database, join, group-concat

I have an SQL setup akin to the following:

ARTICLES

- id (PK)
- name

TAGS

- id (PK)
- tag

...and a third table logging associations between the two, since there can be multiple tags to each article:

ARTICLE_TAG_ASSOCS

- id (PK)
- article_id (FK)
- tag_id (FK)

**Question: how to find articles that have a particular tag?**

The best I could come up with was this:

```
SELECT
    name, GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN tag = 'some-tag' THEN tag ELSE NULL END) AS tags
FROM
    articles, tags, article_tag_assocs
WHERE
    articles.id = article_id && tags.id = tag_id && tags IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    article_id
```

That's on the right lines; if an article doesn't have the tag "some-tag" then that column shows up with a null value in the "tags" column. **But how can I eliminate that row completely?**

Naturally, I tried appending

```
&& tags NOT LIKE '%some-tag%'
```

...to my `WHERE` clause, before learning that you can't use `GROUP_CONCAT` aliases in `WHERE` clauses. So I tried appending:

```
HAVING tags IS NOT NULL;
```

...to the query, with the same result, i.e. MySQL says it doesn't recognise the column "tags".

Any help appreciated.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/27011 --- `HAVING` works perfectly fine for your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT distinct a.name
FROM articles a join
     article_tag_assocs ata
     on a.id = ata.article_id join
     tags t
     on t.id = ata.tag_id
WHERE t.tag = 'some-tag';
```

It answers your question quite directly.

Note that this also introduces table aliases.  These make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: @Utkanos . . . If you look at the data in the SQL Fiddle, the `id`s don't match, so the above query is producing correct results (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/348aa/4).

Comment: Yeah I just spotted that myself, and I've now got this working. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't fully understand your data requirement, `GROUP_CONCAT` doesn't seem like it is what you really want based on the information you have given.

But anywhoo.. perhaps you could use a subquery?

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        name, GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN tag = 'some-tag' THEN tag ELSE NULL END) AS tags
    FROM
        articles, tags, article_tag_assocs
    WHERE
        articles.id = article_id && tags.id = tag_id && tags IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
        article_id
) A where a.tags is not null
```

Or a `HAVING`:

```
    SELECT
        name, GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN tag = 'some-tag' THEN tag ELSE NULL END) AS tags
    FROM
        articles, tags, article_tag_assocs
    WHERE
        articles.id = article_id && tags.id = tag_id && tags IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
        article_id
    HAVING
        GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN tag = 'some-tag' THEN tag ELSE NULL END) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for this - it taught me something about using sub-queries, and did work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use proper joins (the syntax is 25 years old now).
2. Use straightforward conditions without CASE etc.
3. Add an extra join to tags *just* for the target tag.

I assume that you want all tags, but at least one must be `some-tag`

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct t1.tag) AS tags
FROM articles
JOIN article_tag_assocs ON articles.id = article_id
JOIN tags t1 ON t1.id = tag_id
JOIN tags t2 ON t2.id = tag_id AND t2.tag = 'some-tag'
GROUP BY name
```