# MySQL - match all tags rather than any

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have an SQL setup akin to the following:

ARTICLES

- id (PK)
- name

TAGS

- id (PK)
- tag

...and a third table logging associations between the two, since there can be multiple tags to each article:

ARTICLE_TAG_ASSOCS

- id (PK)
- article_id (FK)
- tag_id (FK)

Via [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499765) I managed to construct a query that would find articles that were tagged with at least one of a number of tags, e.g.

```
SELECT articles.*
FROM articles
JOIN article_tag_assocs ata ON articles.id = ata.article_id
JOIN tags ON tags.id = ata.tag_id
WHERE tags.tag = 'budgie' OR tags.tag = 'parrot';
```

**Question: How can I alter the above to find articles that match ALL tags, i.e. both 'budgie' and 'parrot', not just one?**

Clearly modifying the logic to

```
WHERE tags.tag = 'budgie' && tags.tag = 'parrot';
```

...is logically flawed, since MySQL is considering each tag in isolation, one at a time, but hopefully you get what I mean.

Comment: @Barmar: I'm sure this same question has been asked and answered before, but I'm not sure the question that was identified as a duplicate is actually the same question; I think it would be difficult for OP to extend the answers given to that question into a solution for the question OP asked.

Comment: @spencer7593 I think it's essentially the same question, it just requires an additional join. But since you don't think the OP will be able to extrapolate that much, I've reopened.

Comment: Well handled, @Barmar, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several workable approaches.

One approach is to perform separate JOIN operations for each tag. For example:

```
SELECT articles.*
  FROM articles

  JOIN article_tag_assocs ata
    ON ata.article_id = articles.id
  JOIN tags ta
    ON ta.id = ata.tag_id
   AND ta.tag = 'budgie'

  JOIN article_tag_assocs atb
    ON atb.article_id = articles.id
  JOIN tags tb
    ON tb.id = atb.tag_id
   AND tb.tag = 'parrot'
```

Note that this can return "duplicate" rows if a given articles is associated to the same tag value more than once. (Adding the `DISTINCT` keyword or a `GROUP BY` clause are ways to eliminate the duplicates.)

---

Another approach, if we are guaranteed that a given article has no duplicate tag values, is to use an inline view to get the list of `article_id` that are associated with both tags, and then JOIN that set to the `articles` table. For example:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM ( SELECT ata.article_id
           FROM article_tag_assocs ata
           JOIN tags t
             ON t.id = ata.tag_id
          WHERE t.tag IN ('budgie','parrot')
          GROUP BY ata.article_id
         HAVING COUNT(1) = 2
       ) s
   JOIN articles a
     ON a.id = s.article_id
```

Note that the literal "2" in the HAVING clause matches the number of values in the predicate on the `tag` column. The inline view (aliased as `s`) returns a distinct list of `article_id`, and we can join that to the `articles` table.

This approach is useful if you wanted to match, for example, *at least three* out of *four* tags. We could use lines like this in the inline view query.

```
          WHERE t.tag IN ('fee','fi','fo','fum')

         HAVING COUNT(1) >= 3
```

Then, any article that matched at least three of those four tags would be returned.

These aren't the only ways to return the specified result, there are several other approaches.

---

As Roland's answer pointed out, you can also do something like this:

```
   FROM articles a
  WHERE a.id IN ( <select article id values related to tag 'parrot'> )
    AND a.id IN ( <select article id values related to tag 'bungie'> )
```

You could also use an EXISTS clause with a correlated subquery, though this approach doesn't usually perform as well with large sets, due to the number of executions of the subquery

```
  FROM articles a
  WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                   FROM article_tag_assocs s1
                   JOIN tags t1 ON t1.tag = 'bungie'
                  WHERE s1.article_id = a.id
               )    
    AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                   FROM article_tag_assocs s2
                   JOIN tags t2 ON t2.tag = 'parrot'
                  WHERE s2.article_id = a.id
               )
```

NOTE: in this case, it is possible to reuse the same table aliases within each subquery, because it doesn't lead to ambiguity, though I still prefer distinct aliases because the table aliases show up in the EXPLAIN output, and the distinct aliases make it easier to match the rows in the EXPLAIN output to the references in the query.)

Comment: Interesting - I hadn't realised you could join to the same table twice. Is the different alias naming (ata vs atb, ta vs tb) significant? Would it fail without that?

Comment: Table aliases have to be distinct within the query. One reference to the table doesn't necessarily require an alias, but any second, third, etc. reference to the same table will require a table alias. You can't assign the same table alias to two different references (at the same level within the query) without MySQL objecting to an "ambiguous" reference.

Comment: 10.5k without realising that? I'm guessing your forte lies in other areas. ;-)

Comment: You can make the second query duplicate-safe by changing `COUNT(1)`to `COUNT(DISTINCT tb.tag)`. And here's a side remark to COUNT(1): this is the same as COUNT(\*), only more complicated. With COUNT(\*) you say "count records"; with COUNT(1) you say "select a 1 for each record and then count all records for which this 1 is not null", which is all records, too, only quite obfuscated. Usually, however, dmbs see through this and simply count records, rather then doing all the work you actually tell them to do.

Comment: Thanks, guys, this is most helpful. @Strawberry, alas, yes, I'm a JS guy. Did some crazy, elaborate SQL back in the day but not for a few years.

Comment: COUNT(*) and COUNT(1) are operationally the same, aren't they? Doesn't the processor just convert to COUNT(1) at run time?

Comment: @Strawberry: The optimizer converts the aggregate expressions `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(1)` into equivalent execution plans. When those plans are run, they are effectively the same plan.

Comment: Well, COUNT(\*) means count records, COUNT(something) means count non-null occurences. So they *are* different, but as I said, dbms usually notice when an expression can never never be null and optimize accordingly. COUNT(1) is the same as COUNT('this is not null'); the dbms notices and converts it into COUNT(\*) internally. However there is no sense in writing COUNT(1) when we mean COUNT(*) actually and trust the dbms optimizer to replace that.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner: I would trust a test case that demonstrates that MySQL treats `COUNT(1)` any differently than `COUNT(*)`. It's not a matter of "DBMS usually notice"; it's not a matter of trusting the DBMS to "convert" or "replace" `COUNT(1)`. MySQL treats them the same. If it still bothers you that this is the case, then I'll replace the `COUNT(1)` with a `SUM(1)`.